# Last Date of Next Month: SSRS

Tags: datetime, reporting-services

I have a date, for example, `12/14/2011`.

I would like to get the last day of the next month, which would be `01/31/2012`.

How can I achieve this in SSRS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server: calculating date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539517/sql-server-calculating-date-ranges)

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5539615/168703.
One of your datasets in reporting services should reference a common place for all date functions.  And then you can use the date functions to set parameters.

I have highlighted step by step how to do this for reporting services with screen shots in that link.