# sql get every week start date between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has this data
Date when the employees `reported` and the week `start date`(monday) for that week.
Now they did not work all the dates for example there is no data on week of christmas. 
Is there a way I can add the missing week.So, I will still have the week start date for each and every week. But the report date can be null.

I cannot declare variables.

[image]

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180308/ssrs-default-parameter-values-in-subscription/9180701#9180701

Comment: @JonH I think the link has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @haytem - You must have not read it...The scalar valued functions allow him to make a call to get weekstart_date for ANY date.  It very much is related.  In fact, he could simply call `SELECT * FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[udfCommonDates] (GetDate())` or do a `SELECT get_week_start FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[udfCommonDates] (GetDate())` and load or join to this table.

Comment: Oh my bad, I didn't see this. Yes you are right this is a very elegant solution to this problem.

Comment: the dates they need are missing from the table.. how will a `get_week_start` function help if there are no dates for that week in the table?

Comment: @JamieD77 - Simple you pass in a date to get the weeks that are missing.

Answer (score 2):

With your data, probably the easiest way is this:

```
select distinct weekstart_date
from t
union
select distinct dateadd(day, 7, weekstart_date)
from t;
```

You never seem to be missing more than one week, so just combining each week with the next week seems sufficient.

Comment: distinct with union?  does that make it extra distincty?

Comment: @JamieD77 - union is needed to pull the rest of the query.  Without it this wouldn't work.

Comment: @That's true JonH, but UNION makes the resultset distinct.. just wondering if the 2 extra distincts help do something i'm not aware of

Comment: @JamieD77 . . . Interesting observation.  It is there for two reasons.  First, the first subquery can use an index on the column.  Second, reducing the volume of data from each table is a boost to performance, given the performance characteristics of `distinct`.  However, this is (in all likelihood) a very small gain in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a recursive cte if there are more than 1 week gaps.

```
WITH WeeklyCTE AS 
(
    SELECT  MIN(weekstart_date) AS weekstart_date
    FROM    MyTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(week, 1, weekstart_date)
    FROM    WeeklyCTE
    WHERE   DATEADD(week, 1, weekstart_date) <= GETDATE()
)
SELECT  t.reportdate,
        w.weekstart_date
FROM    WeeklyCTE w
        LEFT JOIN MyTable t ON w.weekstart_date = t.weekstart_date
```