# SQL Server query to return work day weeks start, end dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to write a query that will return the start and end dates for work-day weeks between two dates?

Example:

```
declare 
  @startDate date = '2013-07-01'
  , @endDate date = '2013-09-30'

SELECT WeekData(@startDate, @endDate)
```

Result:

```
Name, Week1Start, Week1End, Week2Start, Week2End, Week3Start, Week3End, Week4Start, Week4End, Week5Start, Week5End
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'July 2013', '2013-07-01', '2013-07-05', '2013-07-08', '2013-07-12', '2013-07-15', '2013-07-19', '2013-07-22', '2013-07-26', '2013-07-29', '2013-07-31'
'August 2013', '2013-08-01', '2013-08-02', '2013-08-05', '2013-08-09', '2013-08-12', '2013-08-16', '2013-08-19', '2013-08-23', '2013-08-26', '2013-08-30'
'September 2013', '2013-09-02', '2013-09-06', '2013-09-09', '2013-09-13', '2013-09-16', '2013-09-20', '2013-09-23', '2013-08-27', '2013-09-30', '2013-09-30'
```

A work-week starts on Monday or 1st day of the month and ends on Friday or last day of the month.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to get start date and end date of the week between two dates in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752136/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-start-date-and-end-date-of-the-week-between-two-date)

Answer (score 2):

Does the output have to be in your exact given format? If you want a complete list of matching dates over the given range, the approach I would think of is to use some kind of T-SQL looping, referencing DATEPART (or DATENAME, as in the previous answer).

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '7/1/2013', @endDate DATETIME = '9/30/2013';

DECLARE @currentDate DATETIME = @startDate;
DECLARE @currentMonth INT, @currentDay INT, @currentDayOfWeek INT;
DECLARE @prevMonth INT = 0, @prevDay INT = 0;

WHILE @currentDate <= @endDate
BEGIN 
    SET @currentMonth = MONTH(@currentDate);
    SET @currentDay = DAY(@currentDate);

    -- see if we need a month header
    IF(@currentMonth <> @prevMonth) 
    BEGIN 
        PRINT 'Month: ' + CAST(@currentMonth AS VARCHAR) + '/' + CAST(YEAR(@currentDate) AS VARCHAR);
        SET @prevMonth = @currentMonth;
    END

    -- see if it is a week start or end
    SET @currentDayOfWeek = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @currentDate);
    IF( (@currentDay = 1)
        OR (@currentDay = 31) -- this would obviously need to be more sophisticated
        OR (@currentDayOfWeek = 2) -- Monday
        OR (@currentDayOfWeek = 6) -- Friday
    ) PRINT @currentDate;

    -- go on to the next date
    SET @currentDate = @currentDate + 1;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess I'm a bit late to the party but I just finished wrestling with this one. Here's what I used to generate the last two years of work weeks (assuming Sun to be the start of the week and Sat to be the end):

```
Declare @workWeeks Table (
    weekStart datetime,
    weekEnd datetime,
    weekText varchar(25)
)

Declare @count int,
        @lastSunday datetime,
        @nextSaturday datetime
Select  @count = 0,
        @lastSunday = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) / 7 * 7, -1),
        @nextSaturday = DATEADD(MS, -3, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) / 7 * 7, 6)) -- Next Sunday minus 3 ms

While @count < 52
Begin
    Insert Into @workWeeks Values(
        DATEADD(WK, -@count, @lastSunday),
        DATEADD(WK, -@count, @nextSaturday),
        CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(WK, -@count, @lastSunday), 101) + ' - ' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(WK, -@count, @nextSaturday), 101))
    Set @count = @count + 1
End

Select * From @workWeeks
```

And you'll get back this:

```
weekStart               weekEnd                 weekText
----------------------- ----------------------- -------------------------
2015-06-14 00:00:00.000 2015-06-20 23:59:59.997 06/14/2015 - 06/20/2015
2015-06-07 00:00:00.000 2015-06-13 23:59:59.997 06/07/2015 - 06/13/2015
2015-05-31 00:00:00.000 2015-06-06 23:59:59.997 05/31/2015 - 06/06/2015
2015-05-24 00:00:00.000 2015-05-30 23:59:59.997 05/24/2015 - 05/30/2015
...
```

You can alter what consider the start and end days of the week just by monkeying with the day adjustment values at the end of the expressions used to set @lastSunday and @nextSaturday, -1 and 6 respectively in this example.

But if I'm reading your original question correctly you just want the mon thru fri of the week right? In that case just adjust by one day in each direction in the insert statement like so:

```
-- For Mon thru Fri:
Insert Into @workWeeks Values(
    DATEADD(WK, -@count, DATEADD(DD, 1, @lastSunday)),
    DATEADD(WK, -@count, DATEADD(DD, -1, @nextSaturday)),
    CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(WK, -@count, DATEADD(DD, 1, @lastSunday)), 101) + ' - ' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(WK, -@count, DATEADD(DD, -1, @nextSaturday)), 101))
```

And you'll get back this:

```
weekStart               weekEnd                 weekText
----------------------- ----------------------- -------------------------
2015-06-15 00:00:00.000 2015-06-19 23:59:59.997 06/15/2015 - 06/19/2015
2015-06-08 00:00:00.000 2015-06-12 23:59:59.997 06/08/2015 - 06/12/2015
2015-06-01 00:00:00.000 2015-06-05 23:59:59.997 06/01/2015 - 06/05/2015
2015-05-25 00:00:00.000 2015-05-29 23:59:59.997 05/25/2015 - 05/29/2015
...
```