# SSRS Subscription Report Processing

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am hoping that someone can help me a SSRS Subscription/Report Query.  I have a report that takes 2 date parameters as default startdate = 1st Date of the Current Month, enddate = today's date e.g. startdate = 01/05/2017 enddate = 17/05/2017.

Though these are default dates when the report is run you can also after the initial run change these dates to anything else that you want.

What I want to do is set up a subscription service that runs on 1st of the month and sends the report to a folder on the network.

What I want to do though is replace the startdate and enddate at the point the subscription is run with the startdate and enddate of last month e.g. on the 1st of May the startdate = 01/04/2017 and enddate = 30/04/2017.

What I thought I would do is create a stored procedure in my report with the relevant dates on it for all scenarios that I will need.  Set the Last Month one's with default values from the procedure.

Now I can see all date parameters that I might need within the subscription set up but I cant see how I can change the default run time ones when the report is just run on a daily basis by a user to the ones I need it to run for the last month.  I know I could just create another report to do this but it seems silly to have multiple reports with only the dates differing and I going forward I am likely to use this logic on other date ranges.

The initial code and idea came from this link "[SQL Server: calculating date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539517/sql-server-calculating-date-ranges/5539615#5539615)"

Thanks

Hi R.Richards, since posting the initial query I have been testing a few things with Data Drive Subscription and I think that one of the issues may be due to date format. My report parameters are just set up as date/time but as stated I am wanting to use a function/procedure to call the relevant date splits.  The code I am using is in the link that I posted to the original query but I can post it here as well if it helps.  When using data driven, if I just use the date default in the report there appears to be no issue but when I select it from the function it errors, the function returns year/month/day timestamp but when I see my defaulted date in the parameter its day/month/year timestamp??

Thanks Phil

Comment: Can you add to your question the expressions you are currently using for the date parameters? Both of them, please.

Comment: Hi R.Richards, I amended my initial query to answer your question but I just wanted to add, I have amended the date format in my function and I can not get the data drive subscription working.  I will see if since making the change this will fix my initial query but I dont think so!

Comment: Okay. I don't think you have to do this in a data driven subscription. I am certain you can do it within the default expression for the parameter in the RDL. But, if the  data driven subscription works, and you like that solution, all is good. :)

Comment: I will agree with you there in regards to the data driven subscription, though its not my preferred choice :)  And I am sure its possible to do through the default parameter but I think it will take some more tinkering.  I will leave the question open just for now in case I still cant figure out how to do it through the default parameter :)